# Entity Framework optional foreign key creating redundant FK field in dependant

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm trying to establish a 0-1 relationship between User and TeamMember using this model

```
public class User
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        public Guid? TeamMemberId { get; set; }

        public virtual TeamMember TeamMember { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class TeamMember
    {


        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 0)]
        public Guid TeamId { get; set; }

        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 1)]
        public Guid UserId { get; set; }

        public virtual MSUCTeam Team { get; set; }

        public virtual User User { get; set; }

    }

    public class Team
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<TeamMember> TeamMembers { get; set; }
    }
```

To tell EF all about the relationship, I'm using the fluent API as follows

```
            modelBuilder.Entity<Team>()
            .HasMany(e => e.TeamMembers)
            .WithRequired(e => e.Team)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.TeamId).WillCascadeOnDelete();

             modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasOptional(e => e.TeamMember)
            .WithRequired(e => e.User);
```

And the tables themselves are defined on the context

```
        public virtual DbSet<Team> Teams { get; set; }

        public virtual DbSet<TeamMembers> TeamMembers { get; set; }
```

This generates the required tables in the DB, but the TeamMembers Table has 3 columns:

1) TeamId (Guid, non nullable): PK and FK linked to Team.Id. 
2) UserId (Guid, non nullable): PK. 
3) User_Id (Guid, non nullable): FK linked to User.Id

How do I make the UserId colum be both the PK and the FK linked to the User table? There won't be a TeamMember entry without both UserId and TeamId but I must be telling EF wrong about what I want it to do.

Comment: Could you also provide the code for the `MSUCTeam` class and your full context?

Answer (score 0):

i really can't test this but try setting the foreign key annotations

```
public partial class TeamMember
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public Guid TeamId { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TeamId")]
    public virtual MSUCTeam Team { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public virtual TeamMember TeamMember { get; set; }
}

public partial class TeamMember
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("User")]
    public Guid Id{ get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)  
{  
    modelBuilder.Entity<TeamMember>()
                .HasRequired(p => p.User)
                .WithOptional(p => p.TeamMember);
}
```

for more information about split table check this [link](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/programming-entity-framework/9781449317867/ch04s07.html);